# How do I combine 3 select statements into one? (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 4 sql statements, each returns 2 columns

```
select count(id) open, sum(amount) from A where status = 1 group by est_id
```

> result: 25 | 4400

```
select count(id) close, sum(amount) from A where status = 2 group by est_id
```

> result:   0 | 0

```
select count(id) stop, sum(amount) from A where status = 3 group by est_id
```

> result: 20 | 4000

I need to return the result of the 4 sql sql statement in one, for example:

```
25 | 4400| active
0  | 0   | inactive
20 | 4000| close
```

regards

Comment: look at `UNION ALL` or if the table is the same, then add a `group by status`, `where status in (1, 2, 3)`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @bluefeet you're looking for the [UNION ALL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) operator.

```
select count(id) as c1, sum(amount) as c2, 'active' as c3 from A where status = 1 group by est_id
union all
select count(id), sum(amount), 'inactive' from A where status = 2 group by est_id
union all
select count(id), sum(amount), 'close' from A where status = 3 group by est_id
```

The column names in the combined resultset will be taken from the first component resultset.